# Why payload is showing [object File] on uploading file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, react-native

I am trying to post a file into API my file is shown in the console, but in API payloads it is showing [object file] on uploading.

This is a function for taking file

```
handleFileChange = (e) => {
const files = e.target.files[0];
this.setState({ document: files });
console.log("Guru4666", this.state.document);
};
```

The state is then pushed into an object called award value.

```
SubmitAward() {
var awardValue = {
  title: this.state.awardTitle,
  award_img: this.state.document,
};
console.log("awardValue", awardValue);
this.state.awarddata.push(awardValue);
}
```

Then the API is called.

```
instructor_register() {
var titlearr = [];
var awardimgarr= [];

const UserToken = localStorage.getItem("UserToken");
this.state.awarddata.map((Data) => {
  console.log("AwardDataa", Data);
  titlearr.push(Data.title);
  awardimgarr.push(Data.award_img);
});
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("first_name",this.state.firstname)
formdata.append("instructor_award_name",titlearr)
formdata.append("instructor_award_img",awardimgarr)

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `${API_AUTH_URL}instructor-register`,
  data: formdata,
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer" + UserToken },
})
  .then((response) => {
    //this.setState({ modalVisibleLoader: false })
    console.log("response.....", response.data);
}
```

Payload is

```
instructor_award_img: [object File]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to append an array to the formdata object. This isn't a supported data type, so it gets converted to a string.

Supported data types are strings and blobs (files are a type of blob).

Append the file instead.

If you want to append multiple files, do it by looping over the array and appending each file in turn.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel — That is not surprising … but I never suggested not using FormData. I only said you should not append arrays to FormData objects.

Comment: Without using formdata, on inserting data, the payload files shows empty.

      data: {
        instructor_award_img: awardimgarr,
      }

then it is showing like this

instructor_award_img: [{}]
0: {}

Comment: @AbhishekPatel — OK. Stop. Really. Read what I actually wrote. You asked a question in which you used FormData. I told you what mistake you make using FormData, and what you needed to do to fix it (still using FormData). Since then you have responded, twice (once deleted) with comments about problems you have if you **don't** use FormData. I never suggested not using FormData. You need to use FormData. You should continue to use FormData. You should just pick one of the ways to use it then I described in the answer you are responding to.