# Zodios: Invalid Body Parameter 'body'

Tags: vuejs3, zod

I am using Zodios for request, Zod for types/schema with my Vue3 frontend.
I'm trying to upload multiple files, It fails on static typechecking of the payload body.

```
const multi_file_schema= z.object({file:z.array(z.instanceof(File))})
api = makeApi({
    method: 'post',
    path: 'some_rest_endpoint/',
    requestFormat: 'form-data',
    parameters: [
      {
        name: 'body',
        type: 'Body',
        schema: multi_file_schema,
      },
      
    ],
    response: multi_file_schema,
  },
```

Uploading file objects, Zodios uploads string instead of files.

Update: Below is how I am formulating the payload.

```
const file_input = ref() // Vue ref, tied to the file input HTML Element
const toBase64 = file =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    })

async function submit(event){
  const file_list = []
  for (const item of file_input.value?.files) {
    const file = await toBase64(item)
    file_list.push(file)
  }
  
  api.post(url,{file:file_list})
}
```

The warning I get in console says  `Zodios: Invalid Body parameter 'body'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why payload is showing \[object File\] on uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72783955/why-payload-is-showing-object-file-on-uploading-file)

Comment: I'm already doing the thing that is being suggested there, looping over the files to get the file objects

Comment: "I'm already doing the thing".  Please show it then.  I don't see where in your included code the files are being looped or appended individually to any FormData object.

Comment: I can add that code as well but the question will become confusing because that's a separate approach that I have tried.

Comment: If your problem is how to upload multiple files in a single request and you don't show how you're constructing the request then I don't know how to help you.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll get back to it shortly with details.

Comment: So now the title completely had to be changed as this approach that you're suggesting doesn't allow uploading as the static validation fails and gives the error mention in the end of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending an array of files: `{file:file_list}`. You need to send a `FormData` object with each file appended to it.

This is the simplest example code I can make:

```js
import { Zodios } from '@zodios/core';
import z from 'zod';

const api = new Zodios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', [
  {
    method: 'post',
    path: '/fakeEndpoint',
    parameters: [
      {
        name: 'body',
        type: 'Body',
        schema: z.instanceof(FormData),
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default api;
```

```js
const file_input = ref(); // Vue ref, tied to the file input HTML Element
const toBase64 = (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });

async function submit(event) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const item of file_input.value?.files) {
    const file = await toBase64(item);
    formData.append('file', file);
  }

  api.post('/fakeEndpoint', formData);
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-y7bua7?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fapi.js) (be sure to view request payload in network devtools after submitting)

4 files uploaded:

[image]

expanded to show the first file:

[image]

Comment: Works fine, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong earlier but there was something for sure that I was missing on.